# Systemd fails to start after removal of encrypted swap partition on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, boot, partition, systemd

In order to resize my boot partition I had to recreate my swap partition. After this systemd does not seem to be able to start.

[image: screenshot of boot]

I am new to Fedora/systemd and don't quite understand where I could tell systemd to ignore the now different UUID of the partition.

What I already did is booting a RescueCD, chrooting into my system, commenting the appropriate line in /etc/crypttab and then recreating the initrd with `dracut --force --kver 3.14.3-200.fc20.x86_64`

The screenshot shows the situation after these steps. **How do I get my system to boot properly again**?

Comment: Did you change the UUID of the partition in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I just did (commented the line) and recreated the initrd and the problem remains. It still says "Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b4b596..."

Comment: It was the kernel boot option. It contained the swap partition as a hardcoded parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't realize that boot menu entries in */boot/grub2/grub.cfg* contained hardcoded parameters for swap partitions. One of them was `rd.luks.uuid=luks-b4b59673-e85b-4529-840f-a9843a27a121` which corresponds to the old swap partition.

To properly boot I had to press `e` in the grub boot menu and then to manually remove the parameter from the line starting with `linux`. Then this modified menu entry can be booted by pressing `F10`.

After successful boot I edited */etc/default/grub* and removed the parameters. Then I updated the grub configuration with `# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Also don't forget to adjust */etc/crypttab* and */etc/fstab*.